# Creating msk file for Illumina Array Analysis CLI Copy number train

Tags: microarray, illumina, cnv

recently I'm researching on how to detect CNV from Illumina microarray data. I found that Illumina has Array Analysis CLI software for this task, and I need to train the CN model myself, since the official `.dat` file is no where to be found.

However, this requires another file: the manifest file (`.bpm`) must be accompanied by a "mask file" (`.msk`), which I cannot find online.

Could you please help me on this issue please? And could you suggest some CNV detector for Illumina microarray? Thank you.